# Configurate cmake library debug target in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, gstreamer

I am developing Gstreamer plugins if it matters. I have a C++ cmake project and it opened in Visual Studio.
Project is recognized and built. But it has only library targets, and they are all listed in "Select Startup Item" combobox.

I want to configure some target or configurate Dll target so it become launchable so I can debug my source by running Gstreamer console pipelines which will use my library indirectly.

I assume I should configure launch.vs.json, but don't know how to do it properly. After I pick one of Dll as active library then VS create new configuration:

```
    {
      "type": "dll",
      "exe": "",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "gstdecmpa.dll (build\\gst_sdk_win64_x64_build_debug\\lib\\gstreamer-1.0\\gstdecmpa.dll)",
      "name": "gstdecmpa.dll (build\\mc_gst_sdk_win64_x64_build_debug\\lib\\gstreamer-1.0\\gstdecmpa.dll)"
    },
```

I also tried to add another configuration:

```
    {
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "name": "MyCustomApp",
      "type": "cppvsdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "gst-launch-1.0",
      "args": [
        "arg1",
        "arg2"
      ]
    },
```

but the last one launches one of my tests, existing in project, rather than "gst-launch-1.0"

Can I achieve my goal by modifying first or second configuration? Or some other approach?

Please tell me how to create launchable target with arbitrary application or at least point me to right direction!

Comment: Aren't DLLs by definition not runnable?

Comment: Yes. But for .sln files and in CLion you always can set up dll target settings to run some application with "Run" button, and you will debug you library that way.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve the goal by generating .sln with cmake.

```
cmake -G 'Visual Studio 17 2022' -A x64 ...
```

In .sln I can set up target properly.

But still not ideal solution. Project doesn't look convenient and It rather look like work around than direct approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Visual Studio-specific variables `VS_STARTUP_PROJECT` and `VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND` to accomplish this. For example:

```
  set_property(
    DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT ${target})

  set_property(
    TARGET ${target}
    PROPERTY VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND
    "PATH/TO/MY/COMMAND")
```